# What is the difference between these two generic declarations?

Tags: typescript, generics

I don't know what exactly the deference .

```js
type CallbackBaseAsyncFuntion = <T>(callback: (response: ApiResponse<T>) => void) => void;

type CallbackBaseAsyncFuntion<T> = (callback: (response: ApiResponse<T>) => void) => void;
```